# Difference between html href and fetch call on a listener to the server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to load a static file on click of a menu item. So in my case '/map' would load in the private/index.html file. For some reason when I do an a tag with an href to '/map' this line of code works perfectly.

```
app.use('/map', protect, express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'private/index.html' ) ));
```

When I try to add an event listener to the menu item instead of the a tag using a GET request to '/map' that same code in my node server does not load the private/index.html file. I'm trying to use javascript and fetch to load the file so I can get access to the response of the protect middleware which checks if the user is logged in.

Is there a difference to the way that href and fetch would make this call and not allow it to work. My fetch call to '/map' is very simple, see below. I also tried to use a XMLHttpRequest.

```
await fetch('/map');
```

Comment: `fetch` will request the resource but the browser will not display it. That's because `fetch` is used to load data from the server *without* leaving the current page. If you want to navigate to another page / simulate a link being clicked, you have to use `location = "/map";` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) is a one time setup middleware, it's not expected to be called in the manner you have here. Additionally, it expects a root path to a folder, not a file, which then makes any files within the provided path accessible via direct URL.

It *sounds* like what you are trying to do here is render the HTML page, therefore you don't need `static`, you just want to send the HTML page back as part of the request:

```
app.get('/map', protect, (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile('private/index.html');
});
```

If you want more control over the HTML being rendered, then I'd recommend looking at a [template engine](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: Thank you James! I used a combination of both yours and Chris G's comment. I also had to use the path.join with __dirname to get the root name. Appreciate the help